# возможно ли организовать показ всех уведомлений что есть на смартфоне с помощью кнопки не выходя из приложения?

Tags: c#, android, unity3d

первым делом хочу извиниться за отсутствие кода, так как вообще никогда с этим не сталкивался, а материала по этой теме почти не нашел... я использую C# + Unity 2020, и у меня появилась задача воспроизвести все уведомления что есть на телефоне по нажатию на кнопку в приложении - выглядеть это должно примерно так: ты нажимаешь на кнопку, и тебе показываются все уведомления, что есть на смартфоне(при этом ты все еще находишься в приложении), ты их можешь посмотреть и потом дальше делать что-то другое...

Пожалуйста, кто знает, я буду очень благодарен: возможно ли вообще такое? и, как лучше это организовать? Если не трудно, Вы бы мне очень помогли...

Comment: Какие сообщения? SMS что ли? Вам нужно использовать Xamarin, а не Unity.

Comment: спасибо за ответ!:) извините, я имел ввиду уведомления, которые приходят на телефон от разных приложений, что на нем установлены, или например оповещение что вам кто-то написал в какой-то соц. сети...

Comment: все, поправил:)

Comment: Ну, Unity предназначено для создания игр, а не обычных приложений. А сделать агрегатор всех оповещений в смартфоне от разных приложений... сдается мне, что такое не позволит система безопасности Android. Иначе бы случился каюк всем банковским приложениям, которые по SMS кодам подтверждают подлинность операций по идентификации пользователя и переводу денег.

Comment: понял, спасибо, может есть какой-то обходной путь? или придется непосредственно с гуглом договариваться?

Comment: если в общем, то мне еще нужно "перенести" экран смартфона в мое приложение, естественно в удобную для меня форму... и прямо из моего приложения, не выходя из него работать с установленными приложениями на смартфоне - что-то вроде unity webview, но там браузер, а тут другие приложения... Я так понял тут уж точно с гуглом нужно разговаривать?

Comment: @Bulson к слову, прослушивать входящие и читать смски на мобильнике в Android - очень просто делается, нужно всего-лишь дать доступ приложению к SMS (вы же видели автозаполнение SMS кода при авторизации в каком-нибудь телеграме? вот это оно и есть). А вот по поводу пушей - не знаю, они по идее, нигде не хранятся. То есть входящие пуши еще можно ловить, а вот пришедшие ранее взять неоткуда.

Comment: Если вам нужно программно получить отображаемые в шторке уведомления - то это можно: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3630879/3212712

Comment: ого, Спасибо!:)

Comment: @aepot выходит, что обоснованно с точки зрения безопасности рекомендуют разделять устройства: одно для работы с банком онлайн, и другое устройство для получения уведомлений и подтверждений от этого банка.

Comment: @Bulson в наше время хоть 10 телефонов заведи, но без базовой грамотности в вопросах безопасности и внимательности, это как тыщу рублей в метро носить в заднем кармане штанов, наполовину оттуда торчащую.